# How to implement plugin manually for Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, hybrid-mobile-app

I have this following script :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
         <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
         <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
         <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
         <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>Apache Cordova</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>

        <h2> Camera Position </h2>
        <input type="radio" name="deviceposition" id="deviceposition_back" value="Back" onclick="onChangeDevicePosition();"/>
        <label for="deviceposition_back">Back</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="deviceposition" id="deviceposition_front" value="Front" onclick="onChangeDevicePosition();"/>
        <label for="deviceposition_front">Front</label>


        <h2> Flash Mode </h2>
        <input type="radio" name="flashmode" id="flashmode_off" value="Off" onclick="onChangeFlashMode();"/>
        <label for="flashmode_off">Off</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="flashmode" id="flashmode_on" value="On" onclick="onChangeFlashMode();"/>
        <label for="flashmode_on">On</label>
        <br/>
        <input type="radio" name="flashmode" id="flashmode_auto" value="Auto" onclick="onChangeFlashMode();"/>
        <label for="flashmode_auto">Auto</label>
        <br/>

        <input type="button" value="Take a picture" onclick="onTakePicture();" />


    </div>

<!— camera preview canvas —>
    <canvas id="camera" width="352" height="288" style="border:2px"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
                                      canvasMain = document.getElementById("camera");
                                      CanvasCamera.initialize(canvasMain);
                                      // define options
                                      var opt = {
                                          quality: 75,
                                          destinationType: CanvasCamera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                                          encodingType: CanvasCamera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                                          saveToPhotoAlbum:true,
                                          correctOrientation:true,
                                          width:640,
                                          height:480
                                      };
                                      CanvasCamera.start(opt);
                                  });

        function onChangeDevicePosition() {

            var newDevicePosition = CanvasCamera.CameraPosition.BACK;
            if (document.getElementById("deviceposition_back").checked)
            {
                newDevicePosition = CanvasCamera.CameraPosition.BACK;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("deviceposition_front").checked)
            {
                newDevicePosition = CanvasCamera.CameraPosition.FRONT;
            }
            //
            CanvasCamera.setCameraPosition(newDevicePosition);
        }

        function onChangeFlashMode() {

            var newFlashMode = CanvasCamera.FlashMode.OFF;
            if (document.getElementById("flashmode_off").checked)
            {
                newFlashMode = CanvasCamera.FlashMode.OFF;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("flashmode_on").checked)
            {
                newFlashMode = CanvasCamera.FlashMode.ON;
            }
            else if (document.getElementById("flashmode_auto").checked)
            {
                newFlashMode = CanvasCamera.FlashMode.AUTO;
            }

            CanvasCamera.setFlashMode(newFlashMode);
        }

        function onTakePicture() {
            CanvasCamera.takePicture(onTakeSuccess);
        }

        function onTakeSuccess(data) {
            //
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I have just tried this After installing the plugin with git here :- https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin. , this code is working and my problem can be explained by an `error of installation of the plugin`
 So, I am asking if somebody can help me to *install the plugin* because with this following steps from here:-https://github.com/donaldp24/CanvasCameraPlugin 
 doesn't work for me ***I don't understand why it is not the first time I try to install a plugin.***

Thanks

Comment: Use CLI tools to install plugins

Answer (score 1):

If manual way don't work for you try out "Online Phonegap build services". It worked for me it may be helpful to you too.It will bind your plugins in your application and will build it for you.
Try out this Solution,4 Step Procedure:

1. Create a Zip File of your project.(Build package->Zip)
2. Update config.xml file with new plugins
3. Build application using Phonegap build services
4. Get .apk, .ipa, .xap i.e native applications

Source:https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18816